# Is there a way to plot multiple polygons on one graph with Python

Tags: python, plot

im learning pythons lib `gmplot` and Im wondering is there a way to plot multiple polygons with this lib.
This is the code that i wrote for plotting one polygon:

```
from gmplot import gmplot

gmap5 = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(10, 10, 7)

x = [5, 10, 10, 5]
y =[5, 5, 15, 15]
gmap5.scatter(x, y, '# FF0000', size = 40, marker = False) 

# polygon method Draw a polygon with 
gmap5.polygon(x, y, color = 'red') 

gmap5.draw( "map.html" )
```

But when I want to plot multiple polygons, I get an error:

`TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'`

This is the code that I wrote:

```
from gmplot import gmplot

gmap5 = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(10, 10, 7)

x = [[5, 10, 10, 5], [15, 15, 19, 25]]
y =[[5, 5, 15, 15], [16, 17, 25, 15]]

gmap5.scatter(x, y, '# FF0000', size = 40, marker = False) 

# polygon method Draw a polygon with 
gmap5.polygon(x, y, color = 'red') 

gmap5.draw( "map.html" )
```

I have also tried to use this: `x = [(5, 10, 10, 5), (15, 15, 19, 25)]
y =[(5, 5, 15, 15), (16, 17, 25, 15)]` but it gives me the same error

Comment: you use the same `x,y` with `polygon` and `scatter` - maybe problem is `scatter` not `polygon`? Did you tired run `polygon` many times with different data instead of single polygon with multidata ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I think your issue is that gmap5.scatter is expecting a list of longitude and latitude points and you're passing a list of lists. I managed to get it to work by iterating over the lists in your x & y lists, drawing them one at a time.

Try this

```
from gmplot import gmplot

gmap5 = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(10, 10, 7)

x = [[5, 10, 10, 5], [15, 15, 19, 25]]
y =[[5, 5, 15, 15], [16, 17, 25, 15]]

for lat, long in zip(x,y):
    gmap5.scatter(lat, long, '# FF0000', size = 40, marker = False)

    # polygon method Draw a polygon with
    gmap5.polygon(lat, long, color = 'red')

gmap5.draw( "map.html" )
```

By doing it like so you should be able to plot multiple polygons.

For example, this also works for me:

```
from gmplot import gmplot

gmap5 = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(10, 10, 7)

x = [[5, 10, 10, 5], [15, 15, 19, 25], [10, 20, 25, 50, 10]]
y = [[5, 5, 15, 15], [16, 17, 25, 15], [25, 30, 35, 40, 25]]

for lat, long in zip(x,y):
    gmap5.scatter(lat, long, '# FF0000', size = 40, marker = False)

    # polygon method Draw a polygon with
    gmap5.polygon(lat, long, color = 'red')

gmap5.draw( "map.html" )
```

As long as the corresponding lists in x and y have the same length there shouldn't be any issue.

Comment: Can you please help me with this also, I see that you are an expert:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56895030/error-when-plotting-scatter-plot-with-gmplot-in-python