# Error when plotting scatter plot with gmplot in Python

Tags: python, gmplot

I want to plot scatter plot using `gmplot` lib in Python.
However, I want to make marker_size different for each plot (for each coordinate). I wrote a code and I got this error:

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'tuple' and 'float'`

`marker_size` values are integers.

This is the code:

```
from gmplot import gmplot
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('tripdataNEW.csv')

def geolocation_scatter(input_data, file_name):

    #extract only coordinates and marker_size and convert them to tuple
    coordinates_data = input_data[["start station latitude", "start station longitude", "marker_size"]]
    coordinates_data = coordinates_data.apply(tuple, axis=1)

    #add tuple coordinates to list
    coordinate_list = []
    for coord in coordinates_data:
        coordinate_list.append(coord)

    # Scatter points
    coordinate_lats, coordinate_lons, marker_size = zip(*coordinate_list)

    # Defult map location
    gmap = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(40.7423543, -73.98915076, 13)

    #Scatter dots on the map
    gmap.scatter(coordinate_lats, coordinate_lons, 'red', size = marker_size, marker = False)

    # Draw
    name = str(file_name)+".html"
    gmap.draw(name)

print(geolocation_scatter(df ,"SCATTER"))
```

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you could have done: `coordinate_lats, coordinate_lons, marker_size = input_data["start station latitude"], input_data['start_station_longtitude'], input_data['marker_size']` instead of all the other codes.

Comment: Thanks, and do you know how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with the line:

```
gmap.scatter(coordinate_lats, coordinate_lons, 'red', size = marker_size, marker = False)
```

While you can pass an iterable with "coordinate_lats" and "coordinate_lons" I believe the arg "size" is expecting a float parameter, not a tuple (hence the error). I not sure it was designed to allow for every individual point to be colored different, it's probably expecting the whole series to be the same size. You could probably just loop over this call to get your desired effect. Like so:

```
.
.
.
# Scatter points
coordinate_lats, coordinate_lons, marker_size = zip(*coordinate_list)

# Defult map location
gmap = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(40.7423543, -73.98915076, 13)

#Scatter dots on the map
for coord_lat, coord_lon, m_size in zip(coordinate_lats, coordinate_lons, marker_size):
    gmap.scatter(coord_lat, coord_lon, 'red', size = m_size , marker = False)
.
.
.
```